# Strange behaviour when converting timestamp with tz using to_char in oracle

Tags: oracle, timestamp-with-timezone

I am asking Oracle to tell me what the date & time will be in Santiago when it is 12:00 midday next Monday in localtime.

The following SQL:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(
            to_char(trunc(next_day(sysdate, 1)) + 0.5, 
                    'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI')) 
    AT TIME ZOME 'America/Santiago' 
FROM dual;
```

Returns: 16-08-21 06:00:00,000000000 AMERICA/SANTIAGO

I want to extract the date, hours & minutes, so I am doing:

```
SELECT to_char(
           to_timestamp(
               to_char(trunc(next_day(sysdate,1)) + 0.5, 
                       'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI')) 
               AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago', 
           'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI') 
FROM dual;
```

Returns: 16-08-21 07:00

Can anyone explain why 06:00 becomes 07:00 when converting to_char?!

thanks in advance

Comment: One mistake is pretty obvious; it may or may not explain what you observed. In your formula you have `to_timestamp(to_char(.......))` but you only have one format model - which goes with `to_char`. You don't have a format model for `to_timestamp`. The string is in format `dd-mm-yy hh24:mi`; but if your `nls_timestamp_format` is different, that may cause problems. Now, question for you: Do you want to know how to do this correctly, or do you want to know what, specifically, caused the discrepancy you observed?

Comment: Note also that calling `next_day` with a number as the second argument is undocumented. You should not rely on it for serious work.

Comment: @mathguy thanks for the response. Adding a format model for the to_timestamp unfortunately has not made a difference. 
I would be curious to know what is causing the discrepancy, because this is the only example in a list of about 15 timezones where i see this behaviour. But also it would be great if there is a better way of solving my problem. The reason I am doing this is because our application uses a database table that represents the offset from GMT for different regions. With DST this changes, so we want to use this SQL to monitor.

Comment: As a side observation, why are you using 2-digit years ('YY') in all your format models?  Have you not heard of a little thing called "The Y2K Problem"?.

Comment: Do you still get this discrepancy if you remove the inner (unnecessary) `to_char`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer; using the "answer" format so that I can post formatted code. I may edit this answer if I can find out more.

First, to isolate the problem, it is best to write the simplest possible example that reproduces the error. This has nothing to do with the `next_day` function, or with the initial conversions - it's all about the last conversion, from timestamp with time zone to string.

In the query below, I select a hard-coded timestamp with time zone literal (displayed on my screen using my session's `nls_timestamp_tz_format` setting), and also the same timestamp converted to string implicitly (also using the same `nls_timestamp_tz_format` model). As you can see, the error is reproduced - and we get more information: When Oracle converts the timestamp to a string, it changes the time zone DST flag (it shows CLST instead of CLT; CLST is Chile **Summer** time, which shouldn't apply in August - that's winter in the Southern hemisphere).

Why this happens is a good question. The first place to look is the time zone files - very likely there is a bug there, and there may be patches. (Patches for time zone files, and updates, etc., should be maintained regularly regardless of this problem.) I am able to replicate this on my system because I am an amateur using a free version of Oracle, which doesn't come with access to patches and updates and such; but this is where I would look first.

If that doesn't help, perhaps it's time to ask Oracle themselves (raise a service request, or perhaps report as a bug).

So - here is my `nls_timezone_tz_format` first, to make sure we know what's happening:

```
select value
from   v$nls_parameters
where  parameter = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT'
;

VALUE                                                           
----------------------------------------------------------------
yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3 tzr tzd
```

Then here is the simple(st) query that reproduces the problem. Note that the "timestamp...." thing is a hard-coded constant (literal), up to and including the time zone specification.

```
select         timestamp '2021-08-16 12:00:00 America/Santiago'  as tz
     , to_char(timestamp '2021-08-16 12:00:00 America/Santiago') as str
from   dual
;

TZ                                           STR                                          
-------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------
2021-08-16 11:00:00.000 America/Santiago CLT 2021-08-16 12:00:00.000 America/Santiago CLST
```

Comment: Thanks very much for looking into the issue in such depth. I will now go away and discuss with our DBA's what the situation is with the time zone updates.

Answer (score 0):

The apparent problem is in the *casting* of the `TIMESTAMP with TIMEZONE` to `DATE`.

Anyway if you cast to `DATE` with the explicite *timezone* everything works fine - see the query below the `dt2` result.

```
with ts as (
select 
   to_timestamp(TO_DATE ('2021-08-16 12:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'))  AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago'  ts  
from dual)
select
   ts,
   CAST(ts as TIMESTAMP) ts1,
   CAST(ts as DATE) dt1,
   CAST(ts AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago'  AS DATE) dt2
from ts; 

TS                                             TS1                           DT1                 DT2                
---------------------------------------------- ----------------------------- ------------------- -------------------
16.08.2021 06:00:00,000000000 AMERICA/SANTIAGO 16.08.2021 07:00:00,000000000 16.08.2021 07:00:00 16.08.2021 07:00:00
```

Comment: I disagree with the initial premise. Why do you think that a timestamp with time zone is cast to `date` data type (implicitly) in `to_char()`? Do you ***know*** this, or do you ***think*** that is the case? I believe the query I posted in my answer proves that this is false; if I call `to_char` on a timestamp with time zone, the resulting string represents a timestamp with time zone, not a date.

Comment: Removed not valid *premise* - I confused it with `trunc`, thank for spotting @mathguy The open problem cause remains...